cfg80211 driver problem on 6.1.22-linux4microchip-2023.04
I'm working on embedded Microchip device with "6.1.22-linux4microchip-2023.04"
I want to connect to it Wlan SDIO device .
when I run the driver I get this error:
"moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_results (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_save_state (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status_ext (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_assoc_resp (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol regulatory_set_wiphy_regd_sync (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_request_region (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_enable_device (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_stopped (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_iomap (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_choose_state (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cac_event (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_register_netdevice (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __pci_register_driver (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol regulatory_hint (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_set_power_state (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_disconnected (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_unregister_driver (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_read_config_dword (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_classify8021d (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mlme_mgmt (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_reply_skb (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_roamed (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_notify (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_radar_event (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_tdls_oper_request (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_elem_match (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_send_event_skb (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_del_sta_sinfo (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_iounmap (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_restore_state (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_freq_khz_to_channel (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_pmksa_candidate_notify (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_vendor_cmd_reply (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_set_master (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_reset_function (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unregister_wdev (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_enable_wake (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt_ext (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_freq_khz (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_hdrlen (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ft_event (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_disable_device (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_data (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_bss_get_elem (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_release_region (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_done (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cqm_rssi_notify (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_auth_timeout (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_results (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_save_state (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status_ext (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_assoc_resp (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol regulatory_set_wiphy_regd_sync (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_request_region (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_enable_device (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_stopped (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_iomap (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_choose_state (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cac_event (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_register_netdevice (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __pci_register_driver (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol regulatory_hint (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_set_power_state (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_disconnected (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_unregister_driver (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_read_config_dword (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_classify8021d (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mlme_mgmt (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_reply_skb (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_roamed (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_notify (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_radar_event (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_tdls_oper_request (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_elem_match (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_send_event_skb (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_del_sta_sinfo (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_iounmap (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_restore_state (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_freq_khz_to_channel (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_pmksa_candidate_notify (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_vendor_cmd_reply (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_set_master (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_reset_function (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unregister_wdev (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_enable_wake (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt_ext (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_freq_khz (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_hdrlen (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ft_event (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_disable_device (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_data (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol ieee80211_bss_get_elem (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol pci_release_region (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_done (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cqm_rssi_notify (err -2)
moal: Unknown symbol cfg80211_auth_timeout (err -2)
modprobe: can't load module moal (extra/moal.ko): unknown symbol in module, or unknown

I have also try to change in the the cfg80211 to be "M" and not "*"
and when I try to load the cfg80211.ko I get the same error .
everything seem to be OK and should work on linx6.1.22  - I have rebuild the linux 3 times now , try to clean and make so it will start from scratch.
every time I get the same error.
I have enable in somdefcofig:
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_MWIFIEX_SD8787=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_MWIFIEX_SD8797=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_MWIFIEX_SD8887=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_MWIFIEX_SD8897=y

in the linux-menu:
CONFIG_CFG80211=y
CONFIG_CFG80211_DEBUGFS=y
CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT=y
CONFIG_MAC80211=y

what information is missing in order to fix this issue?
Thanks ,
this is the driver - I don't think he is the problem ,
`https://github.com/nxp-imx/mwifiex/tree/lf-6.1.22_2.0.0/mxm_wifiex/wlan_src/mlinux

So a number of symbols are reporting as "unknown". Did you inspect the kernel(s) that you have built for any of these symbols? Did you look at the Symbols.map file? Did you check if the expected object files have been built from the source files that contain these entry points/symbols? BTW What was the modification(s) to the last successful kernel that you built and booted for your board?


This is my first use of this driver, all other features are working 100% . the linux is working OK.        2.  how do I check "Symbols.map" what should I see\not see there?    3. what do you mean "Did you inspect the kernel(s) that you have built for any of these symbols?" ?   . maybe you can guide me and tell me what to search which command to run and I will publish . it will be faster I think .    Thanks ,


I have found this   ---->>   "Your cfg80211 module and your running kernel are incompatible. The internal programming interfaces in the kernel change rather frequently, so when you upgrade your kernel, you need to keep modules in synch. (The exception is a few out-of-tree modules that are specifically maintained to work across a large range of kernel versions.) "   .     How can I check the module version?

I have checked :    strings /lib/modules/6.1.22-linux4microchip-2023.04/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko | grep vermagic
vermagic=6.1.22-linux4microchip-2023.04 mod_unload ARMv7 p2v8
__UNIQUE_ID_vermagic178   , so this is OK no?

To avoid any and all comparability issues the simplest method is to use a Linux kernel image, loadable modules, and Device Tree from the same source version and built using the same toolchain in one make (i.e. the reason for make clean). Do you have any reason for not following this simple guideline? FWIW you could probably perform a full kernel (re)build (& install) in less time than (successfully) figuring out what  is compatible (since you cannot clearly explain what you have done).

Why to run a full installation if I only use ~ 50% of the kernel option\drivers? isn't the perpuse of custom linux ?  the linux is working , I have enable what is needed for the wireless SDIO (as mention in all the guides I have found about it ). I did everything ok.   what else can be the problem ?
